# Mathematica parses `Log[a,b]` as `Log[b]/Log[a]` automatically, before any rules

Tags: functions, matrix, replacement

I use the following code to realize quaternions (this allows more flexibility than the quaternions package):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Unprotect[Dot];
Dot[x_?NumericQ, y_] := x y;
Protect[Dot];
Unprotect[Power];
Power[0, 0] = 1;
Protect[Power];
Matrix /: Matrix[x_?MatrixQ] := 
  First[First[x]] /; x == First[First[x]] IdentityMatrix[Length[x]];
Matrix /: NonCommutativeMultiply[Matrix[x_?MatrixQ], y_] := 
  Dot[Matrix[x], y];
Matrix /: NonCommutativeMultiply[y_, Matrix[x_?MatrixQ]] := 
  Dot[y, Matrix[x]];
Matrix /: Dot[Matrix[x_], Matrix[y_]] := Matrix[x . y];
Matrix /: Matrix[x_] + Matrix[y_] := Matrix[x + y];
Matrix /: x_?NumericQ + Matrix[y_] := 
  Matrix[x IdentityMatrix[Length[y]] + y];
Matrix /: x_?NumericQ Matrix[y_] := Matrix[x y];
Matrix /: Matrix[x_]*Matrix[y_] := Matrix[x . y] /; x . y == y . x;
Matrix /: Power[Matrix[x_?MatrixQ], y_?NumericQ] := 
  Matrix[MatrixPower[x, y]];
Matrix /: Power[Matrix[x_?MatrixQ], Matrix[y_?MatrixQ]] := 
  Exp[Log[Matrix[x]] . Matrix[y]];
Matrix /: Log[Matrix[x_], Matrix[y_]] := 
 Log[Matrix[x]]^-1 . Log[Matrix[y]]
Matrix /: Im[Matrix[x_?MatrixQ]] := Matrix[Im[x]]
Matrix /: Re[Matrix[x_?MatrixQ]] := Matrix[Re[x]]
Matrix /: Arg[Matrix[x_?MatrixQ]] := Matrix[Arg[x]]

$Post2 = FullSimplify[FullSimplify[# /. i -> Matrix[( {
               {I, 0},
               {0, -I}
              } )] /. j -> Matrix[( {
              {0, 1},
              {-1, 0}
             } )] /. k -> Matrix[( {
             {0, I},
             {I, 0}
            } ) ] /. 
        f_[args1___?NumericQ, Matrix[mat_], args2___?NumericQ] :> 
         Matrix[MatrixFunction[f[args1, #, args2] &, mat]]] /. 
      Matrix[{{a_, c_}, {d_, b_}}] :> 
       Re[a] + Im[a] i + Re[c] j + Im[c] k ] /. 
    Matrix[{{a_, c_}, {d_, b_}}] :> 
     Re[a] + Im[a] i + Re[c] j + Im[c] k &;
$Post = Nest[$Post2, #, 3] /. Dot -> NonCommutativeMultiply &;
```

This gives me `i^j` -> `k`.

But `Log[i,k]` returns `-i k`, which uses commutative multiplication, which cannot be further simplified.

This indicates that the rule `Matrix /: Log[Matrix[x_], Matrix[y_]] := Log[Matrix[x]]^-1 . Log[Matrix[y]]` is not getting applied. In other words, Mathematica converts `Log[i,k]` into `Log[k]/Log[i]` before the rule can be applied.

Is there a way to make it apply the abovementioned rule anyway?

Comment: Use: `SetSystemOptions["SimplificationOptions" -> {"AutosimplifyTwoArgumentLog" -> False}]` to prevent this.

Comment: @CarlWoll will this affect other sessions as well? Is it a global setting?

Comment: Your subject line is wrong. `Log[a, b]` is `Log[b]/Log[a]`, i.e., when there are two arguments the first argument is the base.

Comment: @CarlWoll that's not documented, is it? Where? Any chance of having that with scoping, inside `Block`? @Anixx, do we need all that code to understand your issue with `Log` simplification?  Probably a *Minimal working example* would be best.

Comment: It's actually not part of the parsing step. If it were, then `Hold @ Log[a, b]` would also become `Hold[Log[b]/Log[a]]`. It's just part of the natural evaluation chain for `Log`.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit then why the ruledoes not work?

Comment: @rhermans For scoping, you can use WithCleanup, e.g., `Module[{old}, 
 WithCleanup[old = SystemOptions["SimplificationOptions"]; 
  SetSystemOptions[
   "SimplificationOptions" -> "AutosimplifyTwoArgumentLog" -> True], 
  code, SetSystemOptions[old]]]`

Comment: @Anixx if you post a more minimal example of the problem I could possibly answer that. If you want to understand the subtleties of the evaluation chain, you need clear minimal examples of behaviour that's different from what you'd expect.

Comment: From the Log function documentation: "*Log[b,z] gives the logarithm to base b."  From [Wolfram Mathworld: Natural Logarithm, equations 4 and 5](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NaturalLogarithm.html), you can easily see that that is an appropriate method for changing logarithm bases.